# How can one Wi-Fi laptop spoil the network for everyone else?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

Lately, our internet connection output can vary from a whopping 12-13 Mbps flow, but other times it becomes utterly impossible to connect. And I've noticed that the latter case happens when my brother uses his laptop. I've checked: He doesn't download anything (I first joked about how every time he opens his PC, the internet goes down). But the process repeated itself too many times to be a simple coincidence.

So my question is this: Can a PC influence a Wi-Fi network connection? And how?

Comment: Search for 'windows network monitor' and ask your brother to run it on his laptop so you can see which processes are using the network the most, could be some programs updating in the background, malwares, etc.

Comment: @ViniciusPinto Does the Windows network monitor show airtime usage, or just bits or bytes per second? Because for wireless networks, it's all about airtime, not bits or bytes per second.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by airtime. Network monitor will give you detailed information about network usage so you can identify which application is causing problems.

Comment: @ViniciusPinto Wi-Fi uses a huge variety of PHY rates (signaling rates) from 1Mbps to 1300Mbps. So a client at the edge of range, pushing just 0.5Mbps but using the 1Mbps PHY rate, is using just as much airtime as client moving 650Mbps of data at the 1300Mbps PHY rate. If you don't look at airtime, you'd think the client moving 650Mbps is the hog, when it's actually no worse than the client moving 0.5Mbps. So on Wi-Fi, if you're just looking at the Mbps without also looking at the PHY rate to calculate airtime usage, you're fooling yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a single client can foul a network, even on Ethernet, but especially on Wi-Fi. Some common ways this could happen:

- Something in the client generates a bunch of RF noise in the band. But this would usually mean that the problematic laptop in question would have it the worst, and you didn't mention that your brother's laptop has problems.
- The client has an older Wi-Fi card that can only connect at slower data rates, or is at the edge of range, where it has to use the old slow data rates just to maintain a connection. If your bother's laptop is connecting at the 1Mbps data rate, it would only need to move 0.5Mbps of traffic for it to hog all the airtime (before 802.11n, the rule of thumb for Wi-Fi efficiency was 50%).
- Multicast and broadcast packets are extra expensive on Wi-Fi, because they have to be sent at a low data rate that every client can receive. So if there's something running on that laptop that sends a lot of multicasts or broadcasts, it can hog bandwidth.
- A client can use a lot of airtime by sending a lot of Probe Requests to scan for Wi-Fi networks. This can be caused by running a Wi-Fi network scanner tool, or even by geolocation software that is trying to see what Wi-Fi networks are around, in order to determine your geographic location.
- If a client is running a buggy Wi-Fi card/driver that doesn't obey the medium access rules, or has been intentionally tweaked to ignore the medium access rules, it could hog airtime. 802.11 (Wi-Fi) has rules about how soon a client can transmit a new packet after a previous transmission has completed. Clients are supposed to wait a random (within limits) amount of time. If one client was biased to wait a smaller amount of time, it could hog airtime by getting on the air sooner than clients that obey the rules. Kind of like line-jumping at an amusement park.
- There are several other kinds of bugs a client could have that could cause problems on the network, that are a bit too numerous and too technical to list. Same with AP (wireless router) bugs. There's lots of ways an AP could screw up to give one client an unfair amount of airtime, screwing other clients.

As for how to troubleshoot this, I'm not sure how to advise you. With a spectrum analyzer and a Wi-Fi monitor mode packet analyzer at your house, a Wi-Fi expert could use those tools along with his knowledge to figure this out.

Without those tools and knowledge, you might have to try things like borrowing or buying a USB Wi-Fi adaptor to use on his machine (disable the internal Wi-Fi card) to see if a different Wi-Fi adaptor doesn't cause the problems. Or you could move his machine close to the AP (maybe just 2m away) and see if the problem goes away. Or borrow or buy a quality wireless router to replace the one you're using today, and see if that works better.

Comment: Great, much better to have a positive answer than a negative. I can now remove my sleep-deprived answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Spiff's answer (which is correct enough) I will add missing points concerning security.

There are various attacking methods which can seriously slow down networks.
It includes various spoofing methods, MiTM attacks, network scanning (for open ports or vulnerabilities) and so on.
MiTM attacks (which are used to steal user credentials and so on) can make whole network traffic go through one computer, so you will experience a wild slow-down.
Also various traffic tunneling methods which are now widely used by hackers and advanced botnets (to hide their bad, sometimes huge traffic) can slow the network too.
Another malware can mine BitCoin or scan your shared files every minute in order to infect them.

So, any malware which uses these (and much more) methods can make your network slow.

I strongly recommend you to scan that computer for malware (using strong antiviruses such as Kaspersky, Norton, and not that free fakes). Also check autostart programs using [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), and if you're good at networking, install tools like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/), [CommView](http://www.tamos.ru/products/commview/) and inspect your traffic.